# How can I prevent CakePHP form dropdown ignoring option matching optgroup?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form field in a view with a drop down selection.

```
echo $this->Form->input('form.selection', array('label' => 'Selection', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $selection, 'empty' => '[None]));
```

The form field obtains its list of options from the $selection variable which is a nested array in order to help make the long list of options easier to read.

```
$selection = array(
    'Section 1' => array(
        '1' => 'Section 1',
        '2' => 'Testing 1',
        '3' => 'Testing 2',
        '4' => 'Testing 3'
    ),
    'Section 2' => array(
        '5' => 'Testing 4',
        '6' => 'Testing 5',
        '7' => 'Testing 6',
        '8' => 'Testing 7'
    ),
);
```

I am finding an issue where if one of the `<option>` texts matches the name of the `<optgroup>` then it is excluding it from the list which I do not want to happen.

Is there a suitable way to fix this without manually creating the `<select>` element and all the options inside?

**Notes:**
For the purpose of this question I have replaced the array of data as it contains potentially sensitive information which I do not wish to share and is only a selection of the full array.

**Development Environment:** CakePHP 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the answer here in the following link:

https://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-FormHelper.html#_select

[image]

Therefore your select form field code should be as followed:

```
echo $this->Form->input('form.selection', array('label' => 'Selection', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $selection, 'empty' => '[None]', 'showParents' => true));
```

showParents attribute should be added and value should be true. Hope this would be the answer.

Comment: Congrats, you just copied my answer and won the laurels. ;-)

Comment: Both you and me copied from the same source. Here giving the link of the source: https://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-FormHelper.html#_select
;-)

Comment: Rudimentary anyway. Keep it up.

Answer (score 2):

I just looked up the [source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2079) of `FormHelper` and found the following.

````
/* While a nested options array will create optgroups with options inside them.
 * ```
 * $options = array(
 *  1 => 'bill',
 *  'fred' => array(
 *     2 => 'fred',
 *     3 => 'fred jr.'
 *  )
 * );
 * $this->Form->select('Model.field', $options);
 * ```
 *
 * In the above `2 => 'fred'` will not generate an option element. You should enable the `showParents`
 * attribute to show the fred option.
````

So you will need to set `showParents` to `true` in the select options. Look here: https://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-FormHelper.html#_select